# Arduino Program for Olimex ekg/emg shield to detect heart rate in bpm as well as show ECG in ElecGuru software

Tags: arduino-uno, shields

The manual of olimex ekg/emg shield provides a link for ShieldEkgEmgDemo code, it can show ecg in realtime in a software ElecGuru. The link to software is also provided in the manual. I need to get the numerical value of heart rate in bpm as well as the ecg. I want to implement this in a larger program where I can use something like this.

```
if(heartRate > 90){
        //do something
}
```

I have an Arduino UNO board and an Olimex ekg/emg shield with electrodes. I tested the shield with demo code and it worked fine. I got a clean ECG on ElecGuru.

Comment: You seem to know what you task entails pretty clearly, but what is your question? is there a portion of the demo code you don't understand?